# Google Chrome's "Inspect Element": CSS Hints?

Tags: css, google-chrome, element, inspect

When writing css on Chrome's "inspect element", it shows a list of possible values once you type the first few letters (e.g,  bac...then it shows a list of possible properties to choose from, such as "background" "background-color" etc.)

I'm wondering if there's a way to access the full list of possibilities, before typing anything at all? For instance, if I typed in "font-family: (...now get me the list of fonts I can choose from without having to type in the first letter of it).

Edit: Well, it looks like Chrome doesn't really give hints for font-family anyway, but you get my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention of that being possible [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles#styles_edit).

It would also be *extremely* impractical (and, IMO, useless) from a user interface standpoint to choose from a massive list, considering there are ~307 standard CSS properties, plus tons of `-webkit-` vendor-prefixed properties Chrome offers.

As to values, I don't undestand how you expect the Web Inspector to guess what you want.

Comment: It would probably be impractical for properties. But it would be nice if I could right-click and select an option see the available values for a property. For instance, text-transform: (right-click to see what's available). Or at least a list of the most commonly used properties and values.

Comment: I suppose the Inspector doesn't want to make assumptions. Best to use it side-by-side with a CSS reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google Chrome 30 now supports this feature!